# Question on line integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

Having a parametrized curve $\gamma: [a,b] \to \mathbb C$ and a holomorphic function $f: \Omega \to \mathbb C$, the line integral is defined as

$$ \displaystyle\int_\gamma f(z) \, \mathrm dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma^\prime(t) \, \mathrm dt. $$

Why can‘t one just substitute $ u = \gamma(t)$, so

$$  \displaystyle\int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma^\prime(t) \, \mathrm dt = \int_{\gamma(a)}^{\gamma(b)} f(u) \, \mathrm du?$$

Maybe I‘m missing the forest through the trees?

Comment: Can't see any problem with the substitution, although I can see that there will be situations where it has to be done rather carefully.

Comment: Sure? But why does one define it so tortuous then?

Comment: And how do you define $\int_{\gamma(a)}^{\gamma(b)} f(u) \, du$?

Comment: @MartinR That's the perfect question to ask here. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you @MartinR - i got it :-)

Comment: Note also that in general, the line integral is path *dependent* and not determined by start point and end point only.